# No match for operator "!=" (c++ iterators)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

The program should be a binary search in a vector. In the end it prints the found element. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> s{"a","b","c"};

    auto beg=s.begin(), end=s.end(), mid=s.begin()+(end-beg)/2;
    auto sought='c';

    while(*mid!=sought && mid!=end)
    {
        if(*mid>sought)
            end=mid;

        else
                beg=mid+1;

        mid=beg+(end-beg)/2;
    }

    cout<<(*mid)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It says that the error is that operator != has no match at (*mid!=sought && mid!=end). If I try to do it on a simple string instead of a vector it works.

Comment: Btw your condition should have `mid!=end` on the left of `&&`, otherwise you can get UB

Comment: And as usual: Don't use "using namespace std". [See here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You know std::lower_bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `'c'` is `char`. The type of `*mid` is `std::string`. `operator!=` is not defined between `char` and `std::string`.

You can change `sought` to:

```
auto sought = "c"; // C-style string
```

Or to:

```
using namespace std::literals;
auto sought = "c"s; // `std::string`
```

Comment: or `vector<char> s{'a','b','c'};` ;)

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but please test for `end` BEFORE dereferencing !! `while(mid!=end && *mid!=sough)`